# sonar.coverage.exclusions doesn't take effect when running Sonar scanner in my case

Tags: node.js, typescript, sonarqube, nestjs, sonarqube-scan

I am developing a node.js project (Nestjs) with TypeScript. I have a SonarQube container running on my laptop (In other words, my laptop is the docker host).

I have downloaded SonarScanner and configured `sonar-scanner-4.6.2.2472-macosx/conf/sonar-scanner.properties` to point to my SonarQube container which exposes port 9000:

```
#----- Default SonarQube server
sonar.host.url=http://localhost:9000
```

Under my project root, I have `sonar-project.properties`:

```
...
sonar.inclusions=src/**/*
sonar.exclusions=src/generated/*
sonar.coverage.inclusions=src/**/*
sonar.coverage.exclusions=src/generated/*
```

As you can see I have clearly said to exclude any file under `src/generated/`.

(In my `.gitignore` I also have added the `src/generated/` path)

But when I run sonar scanner under my project root:
`sonar-scanner -Dsonar.login=<MY_PROJECT_TOKEN>`

The console output contains following information:

```
...
INFO: Project configuration:
INFO:   Included sources: src/**/*
INFO:   Excluded sources: src/generated/*
INFO:   Excluded sources for coverage: src/generated/*, 
...
...
WARN: Could not resolve 2 file paths in [/Users/john/Projects/myproject/coverage/lcov.info]
WARN: First unresolved path: src/generated/myfile.ts (Run in DEBUG mode to get full list of unresolved paths)
```

As you can see above, the log shows me Sonar detected project configuration to exclude `src/generated/*`, but after that it gives warning :

```
WARN: First unresolved path: src/generated/myfile.ts
```

Why SonarQube doesn't exclude file(s) under `src/generated` but gives warning there even though it seems Sonar has detected project configuration?  How to get rid of the warning?

**=== tsconfig.json ===**

I am also wondering does it have anything to do with `tsconfig.json` ? So, tried adding:

```
"exclude": ["src/generated/*"]
```

Same issue exists...

Comment: Try like this `**/mydir/*.ts`

Comment: Tried, same issue.